# Debugging slow find-file performance

Tags: find-file, performance

Trying to figure out why find-file (C-x C-f) operations are taking a long time on Windows 10 with emacs 26.3. I tried to do profiling and got following results.

```
- command-execute                           74  84%
 - call-interactively                       74  84%
  - byte-code                               50  56%
   - read-extended-command                  33  37%
    - completing-read                       33  37%
     - completing-read-default              33  37%
      - read-from-minibuffer                26  29%
       + fci-redraw-frame                    3   3%
       + redisplay_internal (C function)     1   1%
       + linum-update-current                1   1%
   - find-file-read-args                    17  19%
    - read-file-name                        17  19%
     - read-file-name-default               17  19%
      - completing-read                     17  19%
       - completing-read-default            17  19%
        - read-from-minibuffer              12  13%
         + linum-update-current              3   3%
         + fci-redraw-frame                  3   3%
         + redisplay_internal (C function)   1   1%
  - funcall-interactively                   24  27%
   - find-file                              21  23%
    - pop-to-buffer-same-window             11  12%
     - pop-to-buffer                        11  12%
      - display-buffer                      11  12%
       - display-buffer-same-window         11  12%
        - window--display-buffer            11  12%
         - set-window-buffer                11  12%
          + linum-update-current             7   7%
          + fci-redraw-frame                 3   3%
          + linum-after-scroll               1   1%
    - find-file-noselect                    10  11%
     - find-file-noselect-1                  9  10%
      - after-find-file                      8   9%
       - normal-mode                         8   9%
        + run-hooks                          4   4%
        + set-auto-mode                      4   4%
      + normal-backup-enable-predicate       1   1%
     + find-buffer-visiting                  1   1%
   + execute-extended-command                3   3%
+ ...                                        8   9%
+ linum-update-current                       6   6%
```

However, I am not an expert in reading these reports. I am not exactly sure how to go from here. Can someone help?

Comment: How about getting rid of line numbers generated by Lisp and use the built-in line numbers instead?  I.e., Use `display-line-numbers-mode` and forget about `linum.el` ...  The built-in line numbers are generated at light speed and are woven into the display engine itself.

Comment: Which part(s) of the entire interactive process feel slow to you?  (e.g. is it the time from typing `C-x C-f` to being able to type a filename?  Is it the time from submitting a filename to being able to edit the buffer?  etc...)

Comment: Do you see the same slowness when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: @lawlist I tried changing that. It is still slow. But thanks for this input.

Comment: @phils Its the time from submitting a filename until any text is shown in the buffer. Basically the buffer still shows the old text for a long time after hitting enter on the filename. And I tried with emacs -Q too but it still shows the same slow behavior.

Comment: Does the file size affect things notably?  Is it *only* Emacs which is affected?  (i.e. if you open the file in another editor, is the process significantly quicker?)  If it's not specific to Emacs, you might look at your anti-virus software -- they can be notorious for making file ops slow.

Comment: @phils Other apps like Notepad/VSCode open these files instantaneously. Also the files are very small so I don't think that's an issue either. This looks like some emacs specific problem on windows 10.

Comment: Well, I'm running out of ideas.  The CPU profile doesn't seem like Emacs is expending a lot of effort on actually opening the file, so it felt like an external thing, but I've no idea what.  For context, can you give us an estimate of what "a long time" actually is?  And one more suggestion for testing: Is it any faster if you use `M-x find-file-literally` instead of `C-x C-f` ?

Comment: @phils I tried find-file-literally but that is also slow. I would say it takes emacs around 5-6 seconds to load a small C++ file (with `-Q` option - so no other fancy extensions running). It definitely looks like something with emacs but even I can't figure out what.

Comment: That sounds very strange indeed.  I have no idea what's going on there, sorry.  As it seems isolated to Emacs, I would `M-x report-emacs-bug` and see if people on the mailing lists can offer any further insight.  Be sure to include all of the details and the various things you've tested.